# compile C code for iOS armv7+arm64 using clang xcode 9

Tags: ios, c, xcode9, jailbreak, llvm-clang

I'm trying to make one binary for both armv7 and arm64.
I am using this command to compile a simple C file:

```
clang -arch arm64 hello.c -o hello -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk
```

How can I add armv7 to this command to support old devices like the iPad 4? Knowing that xCode 9 stop supporting armv7 in iOS 11?

Answer (score 4):

Just add `-arch armv7`:

```
clang -arch armv7 -arch arm64 hello.c -o hello -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk
```

This will yield a fat binary with both architectures.

Also just a note, you can use `xcrun` to avoid having to provide the full sys root:

```
xcrun -sdk iphoneos clang -arch armv7 -arch arm64
```

Answer (score 1):

As an update to Siguza's answer, the way to get SYSROOT as of Xcode 11 is:

`xcrun --sdk iphoneos --show-sdk-path`

Comment: The question isn't about the sysroot and Siguza's use of `xcrun` means it does not need to be provided at all.

Comment: @trojanfoe I would argue that it's an essential piece of info, without which the OP's attempt would simply fail. Siguza answer as of today does not give the right result for SYSROOT, hence this answer of mine.